# Picking an item out of array and comparing the item name against another

Tags: arrays, swift, random, numbers

Edit:
I am trying to pick a random element from an array and compare it to an item from another array, but I just get the int not the word. How do I use the word to compare?
Example:

```
var cardArray = ["card1", "card2", "card3", "card4", "card5", "card6", "card7", "card8", "card9", "card10", "card11", "card12", "card13"]

var symbolA = ["card1", "card4", "card7", "card10", "card13"]

let rightNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(rightCardValue)))
```

Here i want to check if the number that is randomly picked from the cardArray is in the symbolA array.

Any idea?

Comment: Just get the word by `cardArray[rightNumber]`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is your second array? How you are going to compare string and int? Or elements of second array are also strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var cardArray = ["card1", "card2", "card3", "card4", "card5", "card6", "card7", "card8", "card9", "card10", "card11", "card12", "card13"]

var symbolA = ["card1", "card4", "card7", "card10", "card13"]

let rightNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(rightCardValue)))
```

To get an element from `cardArray` at index `rightNumber` you can use:

```
let element = cardArray[rightNumber]
```

To check if `symbolA` contains `element` use:

```
if symbolA.contains(element
{
    //TODO:
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
but.. when i try to use the let element = cardArray[rightNumber] i get this error : Cannot subscript a value of type [String] with an index of type Uint32´`